# Creating a custom exponential function

Tags: graphing-functions, exponential-function, interpolation

I'm trying to come up with an exponential function that starts at zero, rises quickly (in $y$) between $x = 0$ and $x = 100$ and then slowly levels off as $x$ continues into infinity.

Something that looks like....

[image: Exponential plot]

Comment: $f(x) = a(1 - e^{-bx})$ where $a$ is your asymptotic limit and $b > 0$ is the slope at $x=0$. Is that what you had in mind?

Answer (score 4):

Try

$$ y=\mu \frac{1}{e^{-\alpha x} + \epsilon}+\beta$$

Adjust $\alpha$, $\beta$ $\mu$ and $\epsilon$ to meet your needs.

Note:

- $\mu$ scales the function
- $\beta$ shifts it up
- $\alpha$ controls the rate of growth for small $x$
- $\epsilon$ controls when the fuction starts to level off

Answer (score 2):

If you want a function going from 0 to 100, may be you could use

y = 100 (1 - Exp[-a x])

parameter "a" defines the slope at the origin.